# embarcadero delphi and widechar : simple function that doesn't work

Tags: delphi

I really don't understand why this function doesn't work:

```
function GetNomRepertoireTemporaire:WideString;
var
  PathLocal : array[0..MAX_PATH+1] of WideChar;
begin
  Result := '';
  if GetTempPath(SizeOf(PathLocal)-1, PathLocal)>0 then
  begin
    Result := PathLocal;
  end;
end;
```

When I call it like:

```
var
  t : wideString;
initialization
  t := GetNomRepertoireTemporaire;
```

I wait something like 10 seconds then I get an `AV at 0x000000 address 0000000`

Anybody could explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the warnings Delphi gives you.  Could you list them?

Comment: why widestring and widechar? Why not string and char?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Length instead of SizeOf in your code:

```
function GetNomRepertoireTemporaire:WideString;
var
  PathLocal : array[0..MAX_PATH] of WideChar;
begin
  Result := '';
  if GetTempPath(Length(PathLocal), PathLocal)>0 then
  begin
    Result := PathLocal;
  end;
end;
```

The above code assumes that you are using Unicode Delphi version. As David mentioned in the comment you can change your function to make it compatible with both Unicode and Non-Unicode Delphi:

```
function GetNomRepertoireTemporaire:String;
var
  PathLocal : array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  Result := '';
  if GetTempPath(Length(PathLocal), PathLocal)>0 then
  begin
    Result := PathLocal;
  end;
end;
```

---

Explanation: `GetTempPath` function fills with zeroes the whole buffer it receives. The OP code sets invalid buffer size (twice the actual size), so the function zeroes the memory behind `PathLocal` variable, which results in AV.

Comment: +1 for being the fastest and deleted my own identical answer.

Comment: Don't subtract 1 from the buffer size. The documentation says to give it the size of the buffer, and the documentation also says that the returned buffer is null-terminated. Therefore, you don't need to reserve anything at the end. But if you *do* reserve a spot at the end, make sure to *set* it. Also, note that the buffer is MAX_PATH + **2** elements long.

Comment: @Rob: Corrected (removed -1).

Comment: Well surely your buffer should be `0..MAX_PATH-1`

Comment: No, it should be `0..MAX_PATH`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it works, but... I don't think the "principle" is okay: in **every** other language around, C, and C++, **and** older version of Delphi, I use the word '`SizeOf()`', which was made to precise the max size of the "container".

Comment: ... So, it's very logical to use `SizeOf()`. The keyword "length" (alias `strlen()`, `len()`, and so on in **all** the other languagues (C, C++, Php, and son on)) is made to know the **length** of a string variable. The length, not the size of the container! Using '`Length()`' to express '`SizeOf()`' is a nonse to me, even though there may be a logical explanation "behind the wood" (sorry I'm French I don't know the right expression in English).

Comment: In this code `PathLocal` may be filled with **non-zero** values when entering the function so `Length(PathLocal)` may return *non-previsible* value. I've just had this problem in C with a non-correctly initialized variable that had a `value <> 0` (Compiled under Debian was Ok but under Ubuntu gave me this error). So, maybe the Pascal initializes the variables to '0' (and you just rely on a compiler-specific behavior, not on the principle of programming, which is bad to me), but this is still not logical to use `Length()` instead of `SizeOf()`. May I ask you why is this?

Answer (score 4):

Although this doesn't directly answer the question, it is probably better to call the built in RTL method `IOUtils.TPath.GetTempPath`.

Comment: You are never sleeping, are you? +1 for the shortest solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the help file for the API GetTempPath, you will see the first parameters is the size of the buffer, in TCHARs. (i.e. the number of chars in the buffer)

Right now, you are giving the function the number of bytes in the buffer, which is twice as large as the number of characters.

Change your function like this:

```
if GetTempPath(Length(PathLocal)-1, PathLocal)>0 then
```

Comment: ↑ this answer actually **explains** as OP requested.

Comment: Kind of, @User. This answer does mention that GetTempPath was called incorrectly, but it doesn't say why that would lead to the reported error. Does GetTempPath overwrite the remainder of the buffer, even when it doesn't need to? I find that unlikely. And even if it does, where is the attempt to access memory at address 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using normal strings and avoid the use of `array of char` altogether. It's a good way to handle Windows api calls, because you can set the length of the buffer dynamically and the `SetLength` function will work with AnsiStrings as well as with WideStrings.

```
function GetNomRepertoireTemporaire: String;
var
  iSize: DWORD;
begin
  SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
  iSize := GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, PChar(Result));
  // reduce buffer to the effectively used size. if the api call
  // was successful, the terminating #0 is not included in iSize.
  SetLength(Result, iSize);
end;
```

The Delphi version will decide, if a AnsiString or a WideString is used.

Answer (score -1):

Two things occurred to me reading your source code.

The first one is the call to the method itself. The information I found for the function GetTempPath state that parameters are expected to be Char (8-bit characters). If you really need the temporary path in wide-character strings you probably have to convert the obtained path into wide-char representation after the call to GetTempPath (just a guess, since I don't have the API documentation at hand).

The second point is the passing of the second parameter. According to [Delphi How To](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/howto_get_temp.htm) you have to provide a pointer to the character array. So for your example the call should look like

```
if GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, @PathLocal) > 0 then
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You second paragraph is factually incorrect. GetTempPath, as is the norm in WinAPI has both ANSI and Unicode versions, GetTempPathA and GetTempPathW respectively. We have to assume that OP is a Unicode enabled Delphi, and hence calling GetTempPathW.